# Using SendGrid SMTP Integration for bulk email

Tags: email, smtp, bulk, sendgrid

Is there a way to use SendGrid's SMTP Integration API for sending bulk mail?

Here's what I have in mind:
I need to send a large bulk of emails to subscribers. Since SendGrid docs recommend using SMTP Integration where possible, I would like to be able to make a single hit SendGrid and let it send the whole bulk based on email list. I know this is possible with REST API.

Is this even possible with SMTP?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the SMTP api as well. You can check out the SMTP developers guide to see how to design this, https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/SMTP_API/integrating_with_the_smtp_api.html .

You can also check out another Sendgrid user's implementation to send bulk mail with the SMTP api here, [http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/_net_c_cshap_api?from_gsfn=true](https://web.archive.org/web/20120419145345/http://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/_net_c_cshap_api)

Comment: I've seen the documentation before, but the only thing resembling what I need is adding multiple addresses to "To" field. Does this mean that each of the recipients will have the complete list of destination email address?

Comment: When you use the TO array in the X-SMTPAPI header, SendGrid sends a unique email to each user, so the complete list will not be visible.

Comment: @bwest How can i add X-SMTPAPI header to sendgrid.Mail() ?